# What brewing calendar tools are available?

Tags: software

I'm going to be bringing several styles to a wedding, but this same question would work if I wanted to brew several styles for a competition.  We have a given date for the group of beers to be ready to drink.  Are there any tools that would show me, all batches together, what I need to be doing?  I realize I can put each batch into something like brewsmith and get the dates, but wondered if there was a tool with a consolidated brewing calendar kind of thing.

EDIT 2 Months later:
I wrote my own software to give me what I wanted.  I'm sharing it with the other BeerSmith2 users.  I did a little video of me using the software: [smithalyzer demo video](http://youtu.be/D5H-xLc768o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i use beersmith 2, you can enter several batches and the calendar tool is nice. I will give a calendar view with each step marked for all the batches you have going.
Heres what it looks like: [image: Beersmith screen shot]
Also iBrewMaster for the ipad/iphone does a very nice job with your batch schedule, i like that it will give you notifications when you have to bottle or keg, or when your ready to serve.

Comment: I tried beersmith2 and completely missed that feature!

Answer (score 2):

Northern Brewer has a brewing calender setup on google calenders with brewing time frame suggestions for nearly every variety of beer it looks like.
http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing-calendar/

The "+Google Calender" link on the lower right portion of the calender will allow you to sync this with your existing Google calender account.

You could sync this and individually add your actual brew, bottle, and serving dates....this is basically how I keep track.